# Why are titles of blocks in beamer not translated with the babel package

Tags: beamer, babel, block

Is there a way to change only the title of a build in beamer block? Because the babel package doesn't do it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Translate example into voorbeeld}
\begin{example}
test    
\end{example}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

thanks

Comment: I think this answer can help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/559857/1952

Comment: @Ignasi \deftranslation[to=Dutch]{Example}{Voorbeeld} did indeed solved my problem! Thanks